# what does require() function return in case of require("events') in node.js?

Tags: node.js, events

as far as I  know require function returns a object, so the syntax to import EventEmitter class from events module should be like this: **var {EventEmitter} = require('events');**

but I am confused beacause  this syntax also works: **var EventEmitter = require('events');**
and still EventEmitter in second on works as class.!!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a bit of oddity in how the `events` module does its exports.  It reassigns `module.exports` to be the `EventEmitter` class constructor and it also puts a property on that constructor so you can use either one.

This allows you to this any of these:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

// any of these work
const e1 = new EventEmitter();
const e2 = new EventEmitter.EventEmitter();
```

Or, you can do:

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');
const e3 = new EventEmitter();
```

The last one works because `.EventEmitter` is exported.

---

You can see this in the [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/4b17d8838ab979defd99e12c2d1c7f261a6219ee/lib/events.js#L215) where both the exports object and a property on the exports object are both a reference to the same constructor:

```
// constructor
function EventEmitter(opts) {
  EventEmitter.init.call(this, opts);
}

// main export is actually  the above function
module.exports = EventEmitter;

// and that function has a property too that is also the constructor
EventEmitter.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;
```

This lets you use it either of the two ways you mention.